# Database structure for multiple languages

Tags: mysql, localization

I am going to be working on a mysql web app to add support for multiple languages.

The application was never originally designed with multiple languages in mind.

The basic table structure of the existing content looks something like this:

```
TABLE documents
  id
  title
  body
```

My thought was to just add more columns to the table for languages as needed:

```
TABLE documents
  id
  title_english
  body_english
  title_french
  body_french
  etc
```

However I have not worked on localization before, so before I go too far down this road, I am wondering what others think of this approach.   Is this a feasible way of structuring the database for localization?  Are there drawbacks to this approach?  Should I be breaking each language out into a separate table instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to have structure something like this:

```
TABLE document_in_language
    id
    document_id (FK to documents table)
    language
    title
    body
    etc.
```

There would be a unique composite index on `(document_id, language)`. The `documents` table would only contain the language-agnostic attributes, such as the author.